# Execute a command in a new cygwin console

Tags: cygwin

I want to do something similar to this using cmd in windows:

```
start dir c:\
```

A new console should open with the output of dir c:.
For Cygwin i tried this:

```
cmd /c start bash 'ls c:\\'
```

The first part will open a new console, but I dont know how to output the result in the new console.

Comment: ohh I got it, i guess its cmd /c start 'command'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cygstart` to start a program in a new console. Or run it in one of Cygwin's other terminals: mintty, rxvt(-unicode), xterm.

Answer (score 2):

`cygstart` is good, but not really meant for what is being asked. You can think of `cygstart <filename>` as doing whatever would happen if you double-clicked something in Windows Explorer -- which means it can open files in the default program as well as start executables. However, both `cygstart ...` and `cmd /c start ...` will lose your nice terminal environment, so I'd recommend using something that starts a new terminal window, such as `run mintty`.

For example:

```
man ()
{
    run mintty --title="man $*" bash --norc -c "command man $@"
}
```

would open man pages in new windows so that you can view them while still working in your current window.